# can someone help me to fix my code

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have this code for floating banner on the bottom side by side **left** and **right** , nothing is happend when i clicked the left banner , but when i click the right banner, the banner on the left side was automatically closed , and when i click the right banner again it will direct you to other website BUT the banner will disappear.

And my question is :

1. how to make left and right work properly ,left banner can be click and direct to target website and when i click right banner does not close the left banner
2. after banner clicked banner doesnt automatically closed

**This is the code i have on my site :**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#bottomads").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#bottomads2").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
</script>

<div style='width:100%;margin:auto;text-align:center;display:scroll;position:fixed;bottom:5px;right: 270px;z-index:999;-webkit-transform:translateZ(0);' id="bottomads">
<a href="http://example.com" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png" height="60px" width="468px" /></a>
<a href="javascript:hidefreebie();"><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B_YE_mOyP6psSG5qQk9yRG5hcWs" style="margin-left: -520px;margin-top: 45px;position: absolute;middle: 20px;top: 0;" border="0"></a>
</div>

<div style='width:100%;margin:auto;text-align:center;display:scroll;position:fixed;bottom:5px;left: 270px;z-index:999;-webkit-transform:translateZ(0);' id="bottomads2">
<a href="http://example.com" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png" height="60px" width="468px" /></a>
<a href="javascript:hidefreebie();"><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B_YE_mOyP6psSG5qQk9yRG5hcWs" style="margin-right: 25px;margin-top: 45px;position: absolute;middle: 20px;top: 0;" border="0"></a>
</div>
```

I hope i can explain well , and thank you for all the answer.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Problem] Your problemis shown in this image. bottomads2's div is on bottomads.

The solution to this problem is :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#bottomads").click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
        $("#bottomads").style('width', '100%');
    });

    $("#bottomads2").click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });

});
</script>

<div style='width:100%;margin:auto;text-align:center;display:scroll;position:fixed;bottom:5px;right: 270px;z-index:999;-webkit-transform:translateZ(0);' id="bottomads">
    <a target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png" height="60px" width="468px" /></a>
    <a href="javascript:hidefreebie();"><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B_YE_mOyP6psSG5qQk9yRG5hcWs" style="margin-left: -520px;margin-top: 45px;position: absolute;middle: 20px;top: 0;" border="0"></a>
</div>
<div style='text-align:center;display:scroll;position:fixed;bottom:5px;left: 700px;z-index:999;-webkit-transform:translateZ(0);' id="bottomads2">
    <a target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png" height="60px" width="468px" /></a>
    <a href="javascript:hidefreebie();"><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B_YE_mOyP6psSG5qQk9yRG5hcWs" style="margin-right: 25px;margin-top: 45px;position: fixed;middle: 20px;top: 0;" border="0"></a>
</div>
```

Also try to code clean. you will found a lot of blogs out there regarding how to write clean code. i.e try to make classes for same type of styling :

```
.bottomads{
        text-align:center;
        display:scroll;
        position:fixed;
        bottom:5px;
        z-index:999;
        -webkit-transform:translateZ(0);
    }
```

Then the line will be like this :

```
<div style='width:100%;margin:auto;right: 270px;' id="bottomads" class="bottomads">
```

Comment: thanks for the answer i'll try to impelement it on my side

Comment: Your Welcome :) @juicebyah

Answer (score 0):

1. Your bottomads2 has overlayed on bottomads
2. Same reason as above

Suggest you to do more test in https://jsfiddle.net before asking your next question.

Comment: care to explain how to make it un-overlayed or have any good code ? thank you